# Replacing Bathroom Vent Fan

Tags: bathroom, vent, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

Looking to replace a bathroom vent fan in a property that is being renovated. The exhaust fan was not working, upon further inspection it seems to be the motor that is causing the issue.

I want to replace it, but I am not used to seeing bathroom fans that vent out like this. The hole is a circle, not a square, and has one long duct going straight up and out of the roof. The entire fan housing is small and sits in the middle of the duct opening and held in place by two screws on each side. I'm having trouble finding a replacement for this, and cannot find a model number on the motor.

Attached are the photos of the duct and the entire fan.

If possible, it would be great to find a replacement fan/motor unit for this, but that is proving difficult.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be replaced with a modern exhaust fan. The roof vent should also have a cap or shield to keep water from leaking down the duct. I would recommend removing the entire exhaust system and start anew.

It will take less time than trying to adapt a fan motor to a outdated and unprotected roof vent than installing a new system. The roof is already opened as is the ceiling. You'll need to cut the drywall to accommodate the new fan box.

Installing a new duct to the roof and connecting it to a new roof vent  is not hard.

Comment: Thanks for the response, there is a roof cap over the duct, it's hard to see in the photo because the light is hitting it. I agree it makes sense to replace the entire thing, was wondering if there is an old school replacement fan I could find somewhere to just get this thing working for the time being since there are occupants living there and they still want to use the shower. There is another bathroom in the house with the same type of venting system but that fan is working, so they currently don't want to go down the route of replacing the entire thing with a modern exhaust right now.

Comment: @JarrodSampson- Your fan motor i a split phase. These are readily available and vary in size. Look at old motor UL ratings. It should list :voltage, Amperage, wattage, etc. Also it may just need to be taken apart and cleaned; also fairly simple. Or use compressed air or contact cleaner.

Comment: Fan motors get gunked-up over time. Cleaning it with a solvent may get it going. Nothing too harsh, though. Rubbing alcohol and swabs. 409 (degreaser) works. Dry it fully before applying voltage.

Comment: If you go down the road of changing out the fan, invest in an oscillating cutting tool. (Google Fein Multimaster if you aren't clear on the type of tool.) You'll be able to cut the plaster accurately without breaking too much out. Not sure if it's wire or wood lath, but the omt will do much better with that compared to something like a jigsaw or a sawzall. Plus, the tool is useful in all kinds of other settings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a new modern unit.  They are far more quiet.  Might involve reworking the drywall however.  If a fan is noisy it's less likely to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use an in-line bath fan.